# MikTeX creates file MIKTEX-UPDATE.TMP which is caught by AppLocker

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

I have a problem with MikTeX in correlation with AppLocker. MikTeX is creating a file called C:\USERS\%USERNAME%\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MIKTEX-UPDATE.TMP during installation and this is caught by AppLocker as an executable at an unsafe location.

This behaviour is discouraged by our IT and hence I have to comply with it. Do you have any ideas, how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Report it in the miktex issue tracker. But imho your IT should do something about it. TMP is a standard extension for a temporary file and the TEMP folder is the standard location for such files.

Comment: I thought so as well, nevertheless created the issue at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/91

Comment: Have you tried the portable install?

Answer (score 1):

According to Christian Schenk (https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/91), MIKTEX-UPDATE.TMP is only created, when using the MikTeX Update shortcut (not administrative mode) from the start menu. This then creates a copy of the executable (the tmp), which is called thereafter. So my issue was the missing understanding of where the tmp is actually created.